# How do i get it to scale my UIimage to a different size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an image formed by a number of sublayers on a UIView, and then it takes a screenshot as so:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(object.bounds.size);
        [object.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then it puts it onto a button:

```
[objectButton setImage:screenShot forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But the image displays at it's own size, so if the button isn't the same size as the image then i have a problem of it not making the image bigger or smaller.

How can i get it to change the size of the image to the size of the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this category -

.h file -

```
@interface UIImage (UIImageAdditions)
- (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size;
@end
```

.m file -

```
@implementation UIImage (UIImageAdditions)

- (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height), self.CGImage);

    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage;
}

@end
```

you can call it like this -

```
[imageObject scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(weight, height)];
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the contentMode on the UIButton to scale to fit. This will adjust the size of the image to not be larger than the bounds of the button. Also set the image as the background Image of the button instead of the image.

```
objectButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[objectButton setBackgroundImage:image forStage:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still displays the same as it did before.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this,

```
[objectButton setBackgroundImage:screenShot forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```